# Strange Behaviour of Missing Values when drawn from a DataFrame/Series

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, nan

I am experiencing some very strange behaviour of missing values when working in pandas, its FREAKING ME OUT.

Observe the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy import nan as NA
from pandas import DataFame

In [1]: L1 = [NA, NA]
In [2]: L1
Out[2]: [nan, nan]
In [3]: set(L1)
Out[3]: {nan}
```

All so far so good, as expected, the set of the list L1 contains a single NA value. But now I am utterly flummoxed by what happens when you do exactly the same thing but based on a list drawn from a data frame series

```
In [4]: EG = DataFrame(np.random.rand(10), columns = ['Data'])
In [5]: EG['Data'][5:7] = NA
In [6]: L2 = list(EG['Data'][5:7])
In [7]: L2
Out[8]: [nan, nan]
In [9]: set(L2)
Out[9]: {nan, nan}
```

What is happening here? Why are the sets different when the lists they are based on appear to be exactly the same?

I did a bit of digging, thinking maybe the type was different (which would seem surprising given that the NA values were created in what seem to me to be exactly the same way). See the following:

```
In [10]: type(L1[0])
Out[10]: float
In [11]: type(L1[1])
Out[11]: float
In [12]: type(L2[0])
Out[12]: numpy.float64
In [13]: type(L2[1])
Out[13]: numpy.float64
```

So clearly the types are different, which already sort of blows my mind, but what if I convert each element of L2 to be a float just like in L1, the odd set behaviour should disappear:

```
In [14]: L3 = [float(elem) for elem in L2]
In [15]: L3
Out[15]: [nan, nan]
In [16]: type(L3[0])
Out[16]: float
In [17]: type(L3[1])
Out[17]: float 
In [18]: set(L3)
Out[18]: {nan, nan}
```

The problem persists even when the type of elements in L3 are exactly the same as those in  L1.

Can someone please help?

I am relying on the regular functioning  of set(L) when aggregating data using groupby. I noticed this problem and its driving me crazy. I would be interested to learn about work arounds, but I am more wondering what the heck is going on here....

help please...

EDIT: IN RESPONSE TO USER COMMENT I POST THE CODE THAT I AM ACTUALLY TRYING TO AGGREGATE DATA WITH. I'M NOT SURE THIS CHANGES THE DIMENSIONS OF THE PROBLEM, BUT IT MAY AIDE IN UNDERSTANDING WHY IT IS SO FRUSTRATING:

```
def NoActionRequired(x):
""" This function is used to aggregate the data that is believed to be equal within multi line/day groups. It puts the data 
    into a list and then if that list forms a set of length 1 (which it must if the data are in fact equal) then the single
    value contained in the set is returned, otherwise the list is returned. This allows for the fact that we may be wrong about
    the equality of the data, and it is something that can be tested after aggreagation."""

    L = list(x)
    S = set(L)
    if len(S) == 1:
        return S.pop()
    else:
        return L

DFGrouped['Data'].agg(NoActionRequired)
```

The idea being that if all the data in the group are identical a single value is returned, otherwise a list of the data.

Comment: workaround could be converting NA to None - `set([None if np.isnan(x) else x for x in pd.Series([NA, NA])]) == set([None])`. I still don't get why it works for list

Comment: I also suggest to add more of your code, may be you can use numpy/pandas operations instead of createing sets, you have to keep in mind that numpy.NaN != numpy.NaN, you can't test equality like this

Comment: I could add the actual code I am using to aggregate, but the functional parts are basically the same as what is presented here. It just seems like very strange behaviour...

Comment: Also changing the elements to None I don't think helps as I want a missing value to be returned not None (i.e. nothing). I suppose I could add an if statement to that effect, but its not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The only explanation I see now is that all `NA` in the first list are the same objects:

```
>>> L1 = [NA, NA]
>>> L1
[nan, nan]
>>> L1[0] is L1[1]
True
```

While objects in the second list are different objects:

```
>>> L2 = list(pd.Series([NA, NA]))
>>> L2
[nan, nan]
>>> L2[0] is L2[1]
False
```

As about your function, I suggest to use [pandas.Series.unique()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unique.html) instead of set, something like:

```
def NoActionRequired(x):
    # ...    
    S = x.unique()
    if len(S) == 1:
        return S[0]
    else:
        return list(x)
```

Looks like `unique()` works good with `NaN`:

```
>>> pd.Series([NA, NA]).unique()
array([ nan])
```

**edit** to check if NA is in list, you can use np.isnan() function:

```
>>> L = [NA, 1, 2]
>>> np.isnan(L)
array([ True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Does this seem strange to you? Its seems nuts to me. What can I do to make this work?

Comment: @WoodyPride it could be something in constructor of Series. See updated answer

Comment: thanks that works great. I guess the reasons will have to remain a mystery for now. One small correction though, I am returning list(x) not list(S) in the final branch. Thanks

Comment: @WoodyPride yes, corrected last branch. I think it's always better to find pandas alternative to native python, it's usually optimized for vectorized procession

Comment: I think the reasons could be seen in numpy source code, if you have time to do it

Comment: Thanks that's a good tip re: pandas alternative. I'm kind of a daytripper into programming in many ways, so although it would do me good to look at source code, it might take me a year to get to understand it...

Comment: A follow on problem is now I have lists with NA in them, but no means of testing that fact as NA in List not working....

Comment: I can only test the presence of NA values by doing : np.ma.masked in list(np.ma.masked_invalid(DF[data][1]))